# Congruence Implication with $2^k$

Tags: linear-algebra, modular-arithmetic, congruence-relations

For $k \geq 3$ I have to show the following implication:
$$  (-1)^i5^j \equiv  (-1)^m5^n \mod2^k \Rightarrow (-1)^i \equiv (-1)^m \mod4$$

I have tried a few things but I couldn´t solve it, I would appreciate any help!

Comment: Since $(-1)^t$ is either $1$ or $-1$, knowing that $(-1)^i\equiv (-1)^m \pmod 4$ is the same as saying that they are equal as integers.

Comment: I am aware of that but still, I am not sure how to show, that that fact follows from the first one?

Comment: Well either $(-1)^i=(-1)^j$ or $(-1)^m=-(-1)^m$ so all you have to do is to rule out the possibility that $5^j\equiv -5^n\pmod {2^k}$ which you can easily do by ruling it out $\pmod 4$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For $k\ge 3\;$ (and even $k\ge 2$),
 \begin{align}
(-1)^i5^j \equiv  (-1)^m5^n \bmod2^k &\implies (-1)^i5^j \equiv  (-1)^m5^n \bmod2^2=4 \\
&\iff (-1)^i 1^j\equiv(-1)^m 1^n\quad\text{ since } 5\equiv 1 \bmod 4 \\ &\iff (-1)^i \equiv(-1)^m 
\end{align}

Comment: But we have $5^j$ and $5^n$ with possibility, that $j$ and $n$ may not be the same, does that change anything?

Comment: $1$ to whatever power is always $1$! Don't forget that congruences are compatible with multiplication, hence with exponentiation.

Comment: I am aware of that fact, but for example, let $n>j$ and due to compatibility with scaling for any integer, we are left with $(-1)^i \equiv (-1)^m 5^s$, where $s=n-j$ or? It has been a really long time since I was calculating these things so, maybe it´s just my lack of understanding the rules.

Comment: I've added one intermediate step. Is that clearer?